# How to use html page as asp

Tags: asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have developed the whole website by using Bootstrap ,there is some sudden changes that services and back-end functionality are to be written using asp.net

My doubts are

1. can i use the same HTML pages for asp.net
            (or)
2. how to change HTML page to aspx page

Thanks in Advance

Madhavan S

Comment: Nothing wrong with using static html / css in an ASP backed page.  If/when you want some dynamic content in your page, it's as simple as changing the extension and adding some ASP specific templating language

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia thanks for responding and what is meant by ASP specific templating language, could you please give me a hint

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste your HTML into an .aspx file.

If you need to preserve URLs for some reason, you could use URL aliasing.

I don't think you'll want two pages - one HTML and one ASPX - with the same content on an external site.

Comment: TIM Thanks for responding ,i need to know is there any tag or any other important thing to be changed so that it'll work perfect when its launched

Comment: From the HTML perspective, everything in an HTML page is 100% compatible with a .NET page. You gain the additional .NET server controls, but you don't need to use them (and probably shouldn't) unless you need server side processing. The only thing I'd watch out for is your Javascript framework if you're using .NET Ajax. I use jQuery, not Bootstrap, but I don't see why you couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

- Paste all code in web forms page (aspx) pages.

  - Put common headers and footers and create new master page and put all things there.
  - Create web forms and use those master pages.

Help : [Master Page Example](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp)

Simple :-)

Comment: Shan Khan Thank you very much

Comment: If it really helped you please mark as answer so that in future people can get help. :)

Comment: Be aware that master pages can mess with element IDs among other things, and you may need to take special consideration with where you place your references to your files for things like Bootstrap and jQuery.